# How to access asp control by ID using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this asp control in my asp page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlace" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="colorBuffer" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

I use this function to access asp control abouve:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById("colorBuffer");
}
```

But elem is always null.Any idea why?I think that some changes made to the name of ID hidden field by ASP.

Comment: Did you check what html is generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var elem = document.getElementById('<%=colorBuffer.ClientID%>');`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('[id^="colorBuffer"]').id;
```